# Scrapy keeps scraping start page despite different get request url

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a scraper to scrape different links using scrapy. Scrapy keeps scraping the links from the initial page.Although `GET` requests are of different urls , response.url is always the same which causes the same page to be scraped. I don't think there is redirection of any kind because links do not get redirected in normal browser. I have also set a random `DELAY_INTERVAL` as well as rotating user agents using [this](http://tangww.com/2013/06/UsingRandomAgent/) . Here's my parse function:

```
def parse(self,response):
        scraped_data = response.xpath("*//h3/a/@href").extract()        
        if self.urls is not None:               #urls has all the different links to be crawled.
            yield scrapy.Request(urls[self.k],callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
            self.k = self.k + 1
        else:
            yield self.logger.info("next page unavailable|LIMIT REACHED")
```

How to get over this duplicate scraping?

Comment: Can you provide more of your spider code and some logs (with LOG_LEVEL='DEBUG') showing duplicate URLs being fetched? Also, you can add a `self.logger.debug(urls[self.k])` statement just before `yield scrapy.Request` to be sure you are actually enqueuing the requests you intend to.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is flawed here and you have a bunch of undefined variables:

```
def parse(self,response):
    links = response.xpath("*//h3/a/@href").extract()       
    if urls is not None:  #  urls is not even defined
        yield scrapy.Request(url[k],callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
        k = k + 1   # k is not defined either
    else:
        yield self.logger.info("next page unavailable|LIMIT REACHED")
```

Try something like this instead:

```
def parse(self,response):
    links = response.xpath("*//h3/a/@href").extract()       
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse)
    if not links:
        yield self.logger.info("next page unavailable|LIMIT REACHED")
```

Also you should avoid `dont_filter` flag if you want to avoid duplicates.

Comment: My apologies here, urls and k are instance variables . For the sake of simplicity i had skipped their details. I've edited the original question. If i avoid dont_filter i get only one result because response urls is always same despite different get url.